# I can not understand how to use buffers in the audio resampling

Tags: c, audio, buffer, signal-processing

What i have tryed:
**Player.c**

```
const int       BITS=8;
int         isPaused=0;
static mpg123_handle    *mh;
static unsigned char    *buffer;
static size_t       buffer_size;
static size_t       done;
char *          resBuffer;
//from global stat!
int outfreq=22050; int infreq=44100;

int resetMp3(char * song)
{
    int err;
    int channels, encoding;
    long rate;
    /* Inizialize */
    mpg123_init();
    mh = mpg123_new(NULL, &err);
    buffer_size = mpg123_outblock(mh);
    buffer = (unsigned char*) malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(unsigned char));
    resBuffer=(unsigned char*) malloc(buffer_size * sizeof(unsigned char) * (1.0+(outfreq/infreq)));

    /* open the file and get the decoding format */
    mpg123_open(mh,song);
    mpg123_getformat(mh, &rate, &channels, &encoding);
    /* set the output format and open the output device */
    int bits=(mpg123_encsize(encoding) * BITS);
    initAudioDev(bits,rate,channels);
    //Add for resampling
    inizializeResample(infreq,outfreq);
}
int playMp3(){
    /* decode and play */
    if (isPaused==0 && mpg123_read(mh, buffer, buffer_size, &done) == MPG123_OK)
    {
        //char * resBuffer=malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*buffer_size/(outfreq/infreq));
            resBuffer=&buffer[0];
            resample(buffer,resBuffer,done);    
            writeAudio((char*)resBuffer,done);
    } else {
        if (isPaused==0) return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
int freeMp3()
{
    free(buffer);
    mpg123_close(mh);
    mpg123_delete(mh);
    mpg123_exit();
    freeAudioDev();
    endResample();
}

void setMp3Status(int value)
{
    if(value==0||value==1)
    {
        isPaused=value;
    } else {
        isPaused=!isPaused;
    }
}
```

**Resampling.c**

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"

#define LENGTH_MS 1000      // how many milliseconds of speech to store
#define RATE 44100      // the sampling rate (input)

struct AVResampleContext* audio_cntx = 0;
int samples_consumed;
void inizializeResample(int inRate, int outRate)
{
    //char out_buffer[ sizeof( in_buffer ) * 4];
    audio_cntx = av_resample_init( outRate, //out rate
        inRate, //in rate
        4, //filter length 16
        3, //phase count 10
        0, //linear FIR filter
        0.6 ); //cutoff frequency
    assert( audio_cntx && "Failed to create resampling context!");
}
void resample(char dataIn[],char dataOut[],int nsamples)
{
    int samples_output = av_resample( audio_cntx, //resample context
    (short*)dataOut,    //buffout
    (short*)dataIn,     //buffin
    &samples_consumed,  //&consumed
    nsamples,       //nb_samples
    (sizeof(dataOut)*nsamples),//lenout sizeof(out_buffer)/2
    0);//is_last
    assert( samples_output > 0 && "Error calling av_resample()!" );
}

void endResample()
{
    av_resample_close( audio_cntx );    
}
```

Now, when I execute this code, the audio isn't clear and resampling isn't done, problably because have wrong something with pointers and buffers.I review this code hundreds of time without find the error.

Can help me to find it and explain right how i should correctly size the buffers?
Now i think another problem is that i can't define what mpg123_read give me, if you explain this i love you.

Library used:Libmpg123 - The decoder function: [mpg123_read](http://www.mpg123.de/api/group__mpg123__input.shtml#ga8023e3b24e8a70d9589c6c7567c54a41)

Resampling Library: [FFMpeg AVCodec Library](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.2/structAVCodec.html).

*Ps: yes problaby a noob question, but after many attempts, StackOverflow is the only thing that can help me, THANK YOU*

Comment: For mpg123, you should probably have a look at [mpg123 output description](http://www.mpg123.de/api/group__mpg123__output.shtml#_details) if you haven't already, and also [this sampple](http://www.mpg123.de/api/mpg123__to__wav_8c_source.shtml). 
For AVCodec, you'd probably need to use a cutoff frequency of less than 0.5 if you plan on downsampling by 2.

Comment: So the cuttoff frequency isn't stable? I plan to have a variable downsampling/upsampling

Comment: @SleuthEye      ????????
How Can I Calculate this on a real time system?

Comment: The cutoff frequency would depend on the application. In particular, using a cutoff frequency above 1/D for downsampling by factor D (or more generally above the ratio `outRate/inRate`) is likely to introduce resampling artefacts. Something along the line of `min(1.0, 0.9*outRate/inRate)` might be a reasonable startup value for the cutoff frequency.